# Enable stackdriver monitoring after cluster creation

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

It doesn't appear to be possible to enable Stackdriver monitoring on a cluster after creation time. Does anyone know if enabling it after the fact is planned in the future?

About to go live and would rather not have to blow away the cluster to recreate it (mostly because setting up the LB routing was rather painful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't appear to be possible to enable Stackdriver monitoring on a
>   cluster after creation time.

This is currently true. Configuring monitoring (enabling / disabling) requires nodes to be recreated because of the mechanism used to turn it on/off (static pods on the nodes). Since that operation is very disruptive, it was not made dynamically changeable.

Using DaemonSets, the technical limitations can now be worked around, so you can expect GKE to make this possible in the future. Unfortunately, I can't give any specific timelines.

Answer (score 1):

This page says that you can enable monitoring on an already created cluster:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/container/clusters/update

> Monitoring is enabled by default for clusters created from the
>   Developers Console and the gcloud command-line tool, but you can
>   verify by running the following command or clicking into the cluster's
>   details in the Developers Console:

```
gcloud container clusters describe cluster-name
```

> The output from the
>   gcloud command-line tool should state that the "monitoringService" is
>   "monitoring.googleapis.com", and Cloud Monitoring should be enabled in
>   the Developers console.
>
> If monitorng is not enabled, run the following command to enable it:

```
gcloud alpha container clusters update cluster-name --monitoring-service=monitoring.googleapis.com
```

Comment: I confirm that the command works. Just enabled in on my cluster using kubernetes version 1.7.2 in the master.

Comment: This is now the only correct answer, as this feature is in stable: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/update